# Does eigen's cholesky benefit from mp?

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I am wondering, if using multiple threads (using fopenmp) would speed up eigen's cholesky decomposition

https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1LLT.html

There is some information about eigen that specific methods can run parallel, but it is not clear which one benefit

https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicMultiThreading.html

If eigen does not have the option of parallel decomposition, maybe there is another option?

Comment: Why not just check with different `OMP_NUM_THREADS=...` values?

Comment: I will, I was hoping before I start making the effort of compiling and testing with openmp that maybe someone has some experience already.

Comment: The second link you gave already says _Currently, the following algorithms can make use of multi-threading: general matrix - matrix products PartialPivLU_.

Comment: That is true, there is a version 3.3 beta2 atm though. This might be an option as well https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicUsingIntelMKL.html .

Comment: I doubt they'll add such a major change as inclusion of new parallelized algorithms in a minor release. And in any case, you can find the docs in the source tarball — just read what they say there. You second link is generated from `doc/TopicMultithreading.dox`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eigen's Cholesky modules do not support multithreading, but there are wrappers for external solvers in the [sparse module](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TopicSparseSystems.html).

The interesting sparse Cholesky solvers would be **PaStiX** (CeCILL-C, GPL-ish) or **Pardiso** (proprietary, Intel MKL).

They both support **LLT factorizations** too.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, as documented [on this page](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TopicLinearAlgebraDecompositions.html), only the `PartialPivLU` has implicit multithreading support (i.e., it involves large products which are multithreaded).
Essentially the only thing which is explicitly parallelized at the moment are (large enough) matrix-matrix products.